# Not able to submit the form via submit_tag without refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, will-paginate

I am using Rails 4 and added a will_paginate gem. After adding this gem , submit button needs page refreshment to submit the form. Button get selected on clicking the submit button without refreshing the page and its not posting the form. Rendering through tabs is also disabling the submit button. Please help

template file

```
<%= form_tag update_multiple_orders_path, method: :put do %>
<tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= order.user.name %></td>

    <td><%= order.total_items %></td>
    <td>Rs. <%= order.price %></td>
    <td><%= order.contact_no %></td>
    <td><%= order.delivery_address %>, <%= order.state %>, <%= order.country %>-<%= order.pincode %></td>
    <td><%= link_to image_tag('menu_img/view.png'), order_items_path(order)%></td>
    <td><%=check_status(order.id,order.status)%></td>
    <%= fields_for "orders[]", order do |fields| %>
            <td><%= fields.check_box :status  %></td>

      <%end%>


  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="text-align:right;padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px "><%=submit_tag 'Change status' %></div>
<%end%><!--end form_tag-->
```

controller file

```
def update_multiple

 orders= Order.update(params[:orders].keys,params[:orders].values)
 orders.each do |order|
  order.save
 end
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to orders_path }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Parameters-

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ljPSjOWCK/Lup/V1qILPQG3Ov9vs0uoDcsc+Os3Q72o=", "orders"=>{"6"=>{"status"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Change status"}

Comment: i'm inclined to close this issue as it's a bit unclear.  update your question to elaborate on what you mean by "After adding this gem , submit button needs page refreshment to submit the form"

Comment: I guess it is noting to do with `will_paginate` gem.Please post the `parameters` generated while submitting the `form`.

Comment: @jvnill -I updated. Button get selected on clicking the submit button without refreshing the page and its not posting the form

Comment: @Pavan- I updated the parameters which get posted when we click on submit button after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @jvnill and @pavan for responding. Finally I found the reason. It was occurring because of turbolinks. I disabled them for specific controller.